# Javascript в IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Не могу понять в чем проблема код работает в Mozille, Chrome, а в IE жалуется "SCRIPT600: Неизвестная ошибка выполнения"
Жалуется на table.innerHTML = '';
Вот код

```
 function chrows(type) {
          table.innerHTML = '';
           var b=' onkeyup=DPCM(this) ';
           table.innerHTML += "<tr bgcolor=\"white\" height=\"100px\">\n  <td ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Похоже что требуется `<tbody>`, то есть сначала формируете все `<tr>` а потом записываем все в таблицу:

```
table.innerHTML = '<tbody>' + html + '</tbody>';
```

Comment: Проверил, все равно выскакивает эта ошибка, я вроде вспомнил в чем дело, вроде бы тег <table> не поддерживает innerHTML по версии Microsoft :)

Comment: Можно попробовать создавать таблицу целиком, то есть:

    <div id="table-here"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElebentByID("table-here").innerHTML = '<table ... </table>';
    </script>

Answer (score 1):

В IE работает outerHTML

```
table.outerHTML="<TABLE><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr></TABLE>"
```

Comment: Спасибо можно закрывать тему.

Answer (score 0):

Бывает. Само по себе добавление элементов в таблицу в IE вызывает проблемы.
Попробуй использовать распространенные JS фреймворки для решения данной задачи. (Советую взять за основу jQuery)

P.S. В IE консоли глянь что имеет JS контейнер элемента table (). Я не знаю как в IE (я не пользуюсь Мастдаем), но в Фаерфоксе можно таким образом подсмотреть список возможных функций для применения к элементу.

P.P.S Если у тебя страница (table) генерируется автоматом, могу дать свой плагин для jQuery, который, думаю, твою задачу решит :)

Comment: Большое спасибо, уже решил задачу =)

Answer (score 0):

Я-бы вам **крайне** советовал пересмотреть своё желание на вставку RAW-HTML **в** таблицу...

Следует использовать контейнер ( например DIV ), и уже в его `innerHTML` вставлять табицу, полностью
( `<table>...</table>` )